# Run combined hexo command from desktop entry

Tags: command-line, executable, desktop-environment, .desktop

I have Debian 9.5 with xfce and hexo: 3.7.1

The question is about throttle my script called "draft":

```
s@lokal:~$ sudo cat /usr/local/bin/draft
#!/bin/bash
killall hexo
cd /home/s/Dropbox/blog
hexo clean

pwd
whoami

hexo g --draft
hexo server --draft  &
sleep 5
firefox 'http://localhost:4000/'
s@lokal:~$
```

What I am trying to get across is to run hexo combined command from a desktop entry. The desktop file is this

```
s@lokal:~$ cat ~/Desktop/blog.desktop; ls -l ~/Desktop/blog.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=blog
Comment=
Exec=/usr/local/bin/draft
Icon=accessories-text-editor
Path=/home/s/Dropbox/blog/
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=true
-rwxr-xr-x 1 s s 179 Sep 21 18:16 /home/s/Desktop/blog.desktop
```

I turned the Terminal key to true to watch messages. I  am  getting  this after clicking the desktop entry:

```
hexo: no process found
/usr/local/bin/draft: line 4: hexo: command not found
/home/s/Dropbox/blog
s
/usr/local/bin/draft: line 9: hexo: command not found
/usr/local/bin/draft: line 10: hexo: command not found
```

The important part of the messages is that hexo command has been not found.
When I run the same command that is attached to *exec* key, the command is getting actually found.

```
s@lokal:~$ /usr/local/bin/draft
hexo: no process found
INFO  Deleted database.
INFO  Deleted public folder.
/home/s/Dropbox/blog
s
INFO  Start processing
INFO  Files loaded in 599 ms
...
```

How to fix the desktop entry and why is it so?

*update*

### Adding some data

```
s@lokal:~/Dropbox/blog$ whereis hexo
hexo: /home/s/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin/hexo
s@lokal:~/Dropbox/blog$ $PATH
bash: /home/s/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games: No such file or directory
s@lokal:~/Dropbox/blog$
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you manually run `/usr/local/bin/draft` from your `/home/s/Dropbox/blog` directory? Where is `hexo`, and is it in PATH?

Comment: @KevinKruse Thank you for the visit. I updated the question after your questions. They actually should be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Purged Nodejs and Hexo installation. Extracted node-v10.11.0-linux-x64 to `/opt/`. Installed Hexo. Typed out in terminal

```
sudo ln -s /opt/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s /opt/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
sudo ln -s /opt/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin/npx /usr/bin/npx
sudo ln -s /opt/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin/hexo /usr/bin/hexo
```